# Set attached to state

Tags: plugins, posts, attachments, post-meta

In the media library every attachment post has an "Attached to" column. I've developed a plugin that adds author profile and a facebook like banner image.

I now discovered that the attachment posts, that are used as profile pictures, are not marked as "attached to".

I used a wordpress console plugin to get `WP_Post` objects of a linked and of an unlinked attachment. But I couldn't find any difference between them that I could use to set it manually.

Is there any way to set the attached ststus of attachment posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are attached to a parent post. So when you get an attachment object, look into `$attachment->post_parent`. If that is `0`, the file is not attached.

The parent post ID refers always to another post in the `posts` table, never to an user. To attach the file to a user, you could create a hidden custom post type and one entry per user. But I don’t think it is worth the efforts. There is nothing wrong with unattached files.

To change the `post_parent` value use [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

Pseudo-code, not tested:

```
$att = get_post( $attachment_id );
$att->post_parent = $new_parent_id;
wp_update_post( $att );
```

Comment: Ah. Okay, I see, thank you! Would there be a possibility to link an attachment to an author?

Comment: Not really. The post parent field is always just an integer, and that will be looked up in the posts table.

Comment: @Julian, you could then attach your authors to a CPT.

Comment: @Julian See my update.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I searched the hooks list, but couldn't find anything matching. Do you eventually know a hook that could be used to modify this information?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You are right. It wouldn't be worth creating a CPT. I had the little hope, there could be an kind of easy way to acheive this. Thanks, thought!

Comment: @Julian Use `wp_update_post()` for that. See my update again. :)

Comment: Its a good point to start. But it would still need CPT, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you need a valid post ID. You could attach the file to any regular post of course, but that wouldn’t look right.